# Javascript If statements in Zapier Code, "must return a single object or array of objects."

Tags: javascript, if-statement, zapier

I am trying to do a simple If function in zapier that returns a number between 1-10 based on another number input. for example if the number input is equal to 7200000 it should output 2. so far i have this:

```
if (inputData.num === '7200000') {
  output = '2';
} else {
  output = inputData.num;
}
```

This is giving me the error "You must return a single object or array of objects."

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,

```
Input Data: ms = TimeEstimate
var d = new Date(1000*Math.round(inputData.ms/1000));
function pad(i) { return ('0'+i).slice(-2); }
var str = d.getUTCHours() + ',' + pad(d.getUTCMinutes());
console.log(str); 

output = [{str}];
```